# sorting groups of related rows by average values while keeping the groups together

Tags: postgresql, sorting, window-functions

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4, but would like a standard SQL solution if possible.
Consider the following table.

```
corrmodel=# SELECT * from data limit 1;
   id    | datasubgroup_id | datafile_id |           sequence           | index | seqindex | margstat | pvalue 
---------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------------+-------+----------+----------+--------
 1033473 |               3 |          10 | GGTGACCCCAAGCTCAGGGCTGACCTGC | 19042 |          |  70.7634 |      0
```

I want to return the query that has the following properties.

1. All rows with the same `datafile_id` and `index` are grouped
   together.
2. The groups are sorted first by average `pvalue` descending, then by average
   `margstat`, where the averages are across each group.

The two tables I am doing this query on have 2.2 million and 3.1 million rows, so I'd like something reasonably efficient. Each group consists of 5 rows. [This solution](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7629542#7629542) by @Lamak
works, but I had some trouble wrapping my head around it, and I think that a solution using window functions might be something I could actually understand. The following is close, but not correct, since the group is not preserved in this case.

```
SELECT datafile_id, 
       index, 
       pvalue, 
       margstat, 
       Avg(pvalue) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY datafile_id, index) AS avg_pval, 
       Avg(margstat) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY datafile_id, index) AS avg_margstat 
FROM   data 
ORDER  BY avg_pval DESC, 
          avg_margstat;
```

Here is the first 10 rows of the query result for one of my data sets. I'd like something like this, but correct.

```
datafile_id | index | pvalue | margstat | avg_pval | avg_margstat 
-------------+-------+--------+----------+----------+--------------
          30 |   781 |      1 |  13.1568 |    0.998 |     12.52546
          30 |   781 |      1 |  12.3585 |    0.998 |     12.52546
          30 |   781 |      1 |  12.3495 |    0.998 |     12.52546
          30 |   781 |   0.99 |  11.9554 |    0.998 |     12.52546
          30 |   781 |      1 |  12.8071 |    0.998 |     12.52546
          23 |  1428 |   0.99 |  12.1711 |    0.998 |      12.6777
          23 |  1428 |      1 |  12.6451 |    0.998 |      12.6777
          23 |  1428 |      1 |  12.8814 |    0.998 |      12.6777
          23 |  1428 |      1 |  12.8969 |    0.998 |      12.6777
          23 |  1428 |      1 |   12.794 |    0.998 |      12.6777
```

Comment: Why do you say that "grouping" is not  preserved? It seems to be. You have all rows with same `avg_pval` and `avg_margstat` together.

Comment: Lamak's `ORDER BY`, translated into your query: `ORDER BY avg_pval DESC, avg_margstat, datafile_id, index, pvalue DESC, margstat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ypercube pointed out in the comments, my query is quite close to the correct answer. The sort by `avg_pval DESC, avg_margstat` is actually close to the correct sort, only incorrect if the `(avg_pval, margstat)` tuple happens to have ties. So one can sort again, for a fixed `(avg_pval, margstat)`, on `datafile_id, index` which will bring the groups back together. Finally, one can optionally sort within the groups, by `pvalue DESC, margstat`, Putting that all together, one gets

```
SELECT datafile_id, 
       index, 
       pvalue, 
       margstat, 
       Avg(pvalue) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY datafile_id, index) AS avg_pval, 
       Avg(margstat) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY datafile_id, index) AS avg_margstat 
FROM   data 
ORDER  BY avg_pval DESC, 
          avg_margstat, 
          datafile_id,
          index,
          pvalue DESC, 
          margstat;
```